# Deploy Docker-Compose YML to AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

One of the projects has shared its docker-compose.yml file. It contains various services. Each service forms a container. I can easily deploy this image in EC2 and get going. However, I want to use AWS ECS only.

How can I deploy that YML file in AWS ECS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS ECS is little bit different from normal docker environment where you directly start the container.

In ECS you need to `create a task with the docker image` and then c`reate a service to run that task`.

So you cannot directly apply `deployment.yaml` file over ECS.

Here's how you can do this manually, https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-docker-containers/

You can always automate this using terraform/ aws cli etc..